# How to insert wp_nonce field within echoed string

Tags: nonce

I can't find a way to properly insert wp_nonce field, without braking the code. 
The code below is from a class function that sends back string, which will be echoed.

```
    $end_data .= '<input type="text" class="ss_title_form_ajax_' . $this->id . '"     limit="133" value="' . $this->native_title . '" size = "60" placeholder=""/>';
    $end_data .= '<span class="ss_title_form_ajax_' . $this->id . '"></span>';
    $end_data .= '<span id="ShowMe_' . $this->id . '">' . ( 60 - strlen( $this->native_title ) ) . '</span>';
    //-------------------------
    foreach ( $this->have_results as $keywords_rf ) {
        $end_data .= '<span class="user_select_rf" data-role="' . $this->id . '">' . $keywords_rf . '   </span>';
    }
    //-------------------------
    return $end_data . '</form>';
```

How to add the wp_nonce in these circumstances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [wp_nonce_field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) with the fourth parameter set to false. This way you can get the nonce field instead of echoing it:

```
$end_data .= wp_nonce_field( "name-of-action", "name-for-the-form-field", true, false );

$end_data .= '<input type="text" class="ss_title_form_ajax_' . $this->id . '"     limit="133" value="' . $this->native_title . '" size = "60" placeholder=""/>';
$end_data .= '<span class="ss_title_form_ajax_' . $this->id . '"></span>';
$end_data .= '<span id="ShowMe_' . $this->id . '">' . ( 60 - strlen( $this->native_title ) ) . '</span>';
//-------------------------
foreach ( $this->have_results as $keywords_rf ) {
    $end_data .= '<span class="user_select_rf" data-role="' . $this->id . '">' . $keywords_rf . '   </span>';
}
//-------------------------
return $end_data . '</form>';
```

If you can not modified the code if the form class, you can use `wp_nonce_field` as described about and insert it on the form string with any appropiate PHP method. For example with [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).